# error could not parse command in python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm following [a tutorial](http://flowingdata.com/2014/05/07/downloading-your-email-metadata/) to be able to read email metadata. I'm getting this following error: `imaplib.error: UID command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']`

the full trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email_metadata.py", line 28, in <module>
    result, data = conn.uid('fetch', ','.join(str(u) for u in uids), '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID FROM TO CC DATE)])')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 817, in uid
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, command, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 1134, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 965, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: UID command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

This is my code:
The full code is in my gist

```
import imaplib, email, getpass
from email.utils import getaddresses

imaplib._MAXLINE = 40000

#connection
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
(retcode, capabilities) = conn.login('my_true_email_addr@gmail.com', getpass.getpass())

print(conn.list())

#print con.list()
conn.select("INBOX", readonly=True)

result, data = conn.uid('search', None, '(SINCE "01-Jan-2014" BEFORE "01-Jan-2015")')

uids = data[0].split()

print(uids)#in bytes
# Download headers
result, data = conn.uid('fetch', ','.join(str(u) for u in uids), '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID FROM TO CC DATE)])')

# Where data will be stored
raw_file = open('raw-email-rec.tsv', 'w')

# Header for TSV file
raw_file.write("Message-ID\tDate\tFrom\tTo\tCc\n")
```

Previously this line `.join(str(u) for u in uids)` was written like this `.join(uids)` like in the  tutorial but I had an error saying `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found` So I converted it in string.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/guinslym/9389f9c73e56175f5f74)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you converted the wrong thing. It looks like the library is working with `bytes` rather than `str`. Try:

```
b','.join(uids)
```

Answer (score 1):

I converted a list of bytes into a string

```
result, data = conn.uid('search', None, '(SINCE "01-Jan-2014" BEFORE "05-Jan-2015")')

print(data)
#[b'2627 2628 2630 2639 2643 2649 2650 2651 2652']
uids = data[0].split()
#[b'2627', b'2628', b'2630', b'2639', b'2643', b'2649', b'2650', b'2651', b'2652']
uids = [i.decode('utf-8') for i in uids]
#['2627', '2628', '2630', '2639', '2643', '2649', '2650', '2651', '2652']

# Download headers
result, data = conn.uid('fetch', ','.join(uids), '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID FROM TO CC DATE)])')
print(','.join(uids))
#'2627,2628,2630,2639,2643,2649,2650,2651,2652'
```